# Need some help on mysql inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, named **matches** and **teams**.

**Matches**:
tournament_id, match_id, score, home_team_id and away_team_id
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0kGm.png)

**Teams**: team_id, team_name
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D41T.png)

My SQL query must result in the filled in team_name for the home_team_id as also the away_team_id
I know that I will need INNER JOIN to get the result, but the only good result I get is the home_team_id withe the team_name or the away_team_id with the team_name but not both. See code below

```
SELECT  matches.tournament_id,
    matches.match_id,
    matches.score,
    matches.home_team_id, 
    matches.away_team_id,
    teams.team_id,
    teams.team_name
FROM matches
INNER JOIN teams ON matches.home_team_id = teams.team_id
WHERE matches.tournament_id = 'WC-1930'
```

How can I get the result of both the team_name for the home_team_id and the away_team_id?

Comment: You have removed your text table in favour of an image. Please revert this and leave the text (you can format this by adding a second space above it). [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Also, you seem to be making a lot of small changes to your question. Please refrain from this and keep to a minimal amount of edits, this can be seen as bumping your question in the recent list and can potentially be misconstrued as a spam tactic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help achieve what you want- adding a second link to teams based on the away team. EDIT: It was pointed out that my change ended up with some duplicate field names so have fixed this as well.

```
SELECT  matches.tournament_id,
    matches.match_id,
    matches.score,
    matches.home_team_id, 
    matches.away_team_id,
    h.team_id as home_id,
    h.team_name as home_name,
    a.team_id as away_id,
    a.team_name as away_name
FROM matches
INNER JOIN teams h ON matches.home_team_id = h.team_id
INNER JOIN teams a ON matches.away_team_id = a.team_id
WHERE matches.tournament_id = 'WC-1930'
ORDER BY matches.match_id ASC;
```

Comment: Please edit and explain what you did and why this helps the OP. Code only answers are rarely much use for *learning*.

Comment: You are also problematically outputting two identical columns. You should be renaming these columns to make them distinct.

Comment: @Martin it's a fair point re the identical names, have edited.  It's not a code only answer, it's sparse but I didn't think it needed much else - feel free to edit if you have something to contribute. The OP seems to have found it helpgul enough to have accepted it!